# How to concat hour with date in python

Tags: python, pandas, date

I have a pandas dataframe where date and hour is in two different columns as shown below -
I want to concat these two columns to have a new datatime column where I can apply pandas window/shift functions. Please share your views.

```
        date          hour
0       20190409       0
1       20190409       0
2       20190409       0
3       20190409       0
4       20190409       0
```

Comment: I'm assuming you meant your data to be something like this:
`pd.DataFrame(columns=['date', 'hour'],
             data=[[20190409,0], [20190409, 1], [20190409,2], [20190409, 3]])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`pandas.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and [`pd.to_timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) and add them together:

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y%m%d') + pd.to_timedelta(df['hour'], unit='H')
```